# How to create Back button using task stack in android?

Tags: android

I want to add "Back" button to my `activity` to be able to reopen the previous activity, I read that `task stack` keeps all the previously opened activities m how can I start the latest opened activity when clicking my "Back" button ?

Comment: It will do this automatically. When you press back on your second activity, your first will reappear. Unless you are calling finish(); on it?

Comment: I want to add a new button on my app UI that works for back button , how can I make it do this function ?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? I see lots of people copying the IPhone back-button - but why? You duplicate a functionality thats already there as a hardware-button. Thats a waste of screen-space (which you dont have much of on a phone) and functionality. I would never press this anyway, I'm used to press the back button thats always there, not the one that may come up in certain apps, just out of habit. Please think about this before you build it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imitating the back button:

```
  Button myBackButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back_button);
  myBackButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(
      @Override
      public void onClick(){
               finish();
      }
  ));
```

[finish(); API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish%28%29)

Comment: finish is called on your Activity